# Angular 4 Router not changing named router outlets based on route

Tags: angular, angular4-router

When I navigate to **/** the correct **NavbarComponent** shows up on the router-outlet named '*navbar*'. However, when I navigate to **/app/dashboard** the **AppCentralNavbarComponent** does not show up on the router-outlet named 'navbar', instead the error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet

is thrown.

**app.routing.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: NavbarComponent, outlet: 'navbar' },
  { path: 'account', loadChildren: './features/account/account.module#AccountModule' },
  { path: 'app', loadChildren: './features/app-central.module#AppCentralModule' },
  { path: '*', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

**app-central.routing.ts**

```
    export const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: '', component: AppCentralNavbarComponent, outlet: 'navbar' },
      { path: '', component: AppCentralSidebarComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' }
    ];
```

**standard-layout.component.html**

```
<div>
  <router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <o-app-alert></o-app-alert>
  <o-sidebar></o-sidebar>
  <o-body></o-body>
  <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

If you want to see better formatted code: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19001

**How do I get Named Router Outlets to navigate to along with the non-named router outlets based on the route configuration?**

There's lots of examples on how to do this with routerLink but nothing really about it by just using route configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure this is supposed to work. Try navigating to named outlets using `routerLink` or `router.navigate()`. There are some answers with examples (also in angular.io)

Comment: So I thought about that but then everytime I route from a page that has another type of 'navbar' to a page with a new navbar component, I'll have to basically make sure I change the navbar component too. Hmmm. It seems really redundant.

Comment: Don't have any more time today to have a closer look...

Answer (score 2):

Okay so actually I figured this out on my own.

Adding the following helped debug greatly.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true})
```

I had to make the following modifications to **app.routing.ts**

```
  { path: 'account/*', component: NavbarComponent, outlet: 'navbar' },
  { path: '', component: NavbarComponent, pathMatch: 'full', outlet: 'navbar' },
  { path: 'account', loadChildren: './features/account/account.module#AccountModule' },
  { path: 'app', loadChildren: './features/app-central.module#AppCentralModule' },
  { path: '*', component: HomeComponent }
```

The **{ path: '', component: NavbarComponent, outlet: 'navbar' }** route was being resolved for **/app/dashboard** so I had to make the route more restrictive.